# How to build streaming API with Ruby Grape?

Tags: ruby, streaming, ruby-grape

I want to build a API with Grape, which could be POST file through http streaming.
How to do that?

PS [grape example](https://github.com/intridea/rack-stream/tree/master/examples/grape) of  [rack-stream](https://github.com/intridea/rack-stream) couldn't work

error info: HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable

Comment: *couldn't work* is not a valid issue description. Where is your code? What is your error?

Comment: What I've tried:
1. Clone files from [grape example][1]
2. sudo apt-get install redis-server in my Ubuntu 12.04 x64
3. thin start -p 9292
4. curl -i -N address-of-api, and I got "HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable"

Comment: Did you start the redis server?

Answer (score 0):

I want to make grape can handle request like this:

```
Net::HTTP.new('localhost', 9292).start do |h|
  req = Net::HTTP::Post.new('/api/http_streaming_post')
  File.open('binary_file.bin') do |f|
    req.body_stream = f
    req['Content-Length'] = f.lstat.size.to_s
    req['Content-Type'] = 'text/html;charset=utf-8'
    response = h.request req
  end
end
```

I don't know how to do it.

After found [reading body_stream in sinatra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24699700/reading-body-stream-in-sinatra), I use sinatra instead.